# Symfony render asynchronous content for Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can i render the twig page in two steps ? 
First load only texts and then after finishing processing put also the data...

Example:

```
return $this->render('page.html.twig', ['text' => $text, 'data' => $data);
```

But operation for preparing **$data** is too long.. so i would like to render page **without $data**, and after finishing process put data separately into page...

Is it possible please ?

Thanks for help

Comment: render the page with a loader og placeholder where your data should be, use ajax to request `data, add it to the page. :)

Comment: You can use hinclude ther's a great doc with symfony https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/hinclude.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible but you can hack it. You should render without data Twig render. And send ajax request another to endpoint then get data variable into your page.

Comment: Sounds good, only one additional question. When I get the data from ajax request, will be automaticly loaded in template or I have to refresh the page.. because inside template Im looping trough data

Comment: If you take from Ajax request you can not use with Twig. You can use it only Javascript. Because Javascript is rendered with your client browser but twig variables rendered your Php engine so back-end.